# angular's getLocaleDateTimeFormat function returns {1}, {0}

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular's getLocaleDateTimeFormat function to display selected date-time in the input field.

`getLocaleDateTimeFormat(this.injector.get(LOCALE_ID), FormatWidth.Short)` function shows `{1}, {0}`

but when i use
`getLocaleDateFormat(this.injector.get(LOCALE_ID), FormatWidth.Short)` and `getLocaleTimeFormat(this.injector.get(LOCALE_ID), FormatWidth.Short)` each separately they display date and time properly.

Am i doing something wrong?

My function is:

`
formattingDate(date: Date): string {

```
if (!date || typeof date == 'string') {
    return '';
}

let localeId = this.injector.get(LOCALE_ID);

let localeDateFormat = getLocaleDateFormat(localeId, FormatWidth.Short);
let localeTimeFormat = getLocaleTimeFormat(localeId, FormatWidth.Short);
let localeDateTimeFormat = getLocaleDateTimeFormat(localeId, FormatWidth.Short);
return formatDate(date, localeDateTimeFormat, localeId);
```

}
`

the thing is getLocaleDateTimeFormat function is not getting date or time or both from date argument

Comment: Can you add stackblitz example?

Comment: localeId is `let localeId = this.injector.get(LOCALE_ID);`

Comment: actually i'm using it inside formatDate function like this: `formatDate(date, getLocaleDateTimeFormat(localeId, FormatWidth.Short), localeId);`

Comment: What I mean is that create a reproduction app (include only things that are critical to this issue) here https://stackblitz.com/ and paste the link here, so that we can try to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Humberd ok i'll try it

Comment: Very often just by doing a reproduction app I resolve the issue by myself just because I dismantled the problem to the smaller pieces.

Comment: Go on Stackblitz, create angular app and paste your code there. Then paste the link to the app here.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is the template e.g. "YYYY/MM/DD" then import locale data:

```
import localeDe from "@angular/common/locales/de";
...
localeDe[10][FormatWidth.Short]
```

There are four members in the array corresponding to FormatWidth enum {Short, Medium, Long, Full}

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this when I faced the same problem. The `getLocaleDateTimeFormat` function doesn't appear to be designed to behave as you expect ie, it doesn't return the format string of the DateTime in the given locale, rather, it returns the order in which a DateTime is presented in that Locale, ie {Date} {Time}.

Looking at some code [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fe691935091aaf7090864c8111a15f7cc7e53b6c/packages/common/src/i18n/format_date.ts#L174), you can see they use the `getLocaleDateFormat` and the `getLocaleTimeFormat` functions and then pass them into a *formatter* function that takes the result of `getLocaleDateTimeFormat`, the time and the date separately and spits out the expected result.

Code Example:

```
function getLocaleDateTime(string locale, string dateTime) {
    let fullTime = getLocaleTimeFormat(locale, FormatWidth.Medium);
    let fullDate = getLocaleDateFormat(locale, FormatWidth.Medium);
    return this.formatDateTime(getLocaleDateTimeFormat(locale, FormatWidth.Medium), [fullTime, fullDate]);
}

// Copied from https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fe691935091aaf7090864c8111a15f7cc7e53b6c/packages/common/src/i18n/format_date.ts#L201
function formatDateTime(str, opt_values) {
    if (opt_values) {
        str = str.replace(/\{([^}]+)}/g, function (match, key) {
            return (opt_values != null && key in opt_values) ? opt_values[key] : match;
        });
    }
    return str;
}
```